# Dictionary lookup efficiency

Tags: python, optimization, dictionary, lookup

I have a list of list of lists to which I want to add a list with summed values from a dictionary based on a lookup.

The code below works but is not fast enough to process the amount of data I have, so the question is how to do this more efficiently. I'm using Python 2.7.

```
people = [
            [['A'], ['B']], 
            [['B'], ['A', 'C', 'E', 'D']], 
            [['C'], ['B']], 
            [['D'], ['B', 'E']], 
            [['E'], ['H', 'B', 'D']], 
            [['F']], 
            [['G']], 
            [['H'], ['E']], 
            [['I']]
        ]

 dollars = {'A': 575, 'B': 628, 'C': 693, 'D': 456, 'E': 1595, 'F': 1366, 'G': 1596, 'H': 2667, 'I': 2145}
```

I have tried (variations of) the following:

```
num_dos = 2 # a placeholder, will be user input

for groups in people:
    groups.append([])
    for i in range(min(len(groups), num_dos)):
        groups[-1].extend([v for k, v in dollars.items() if k in groups[i]])
    groups[-1] = sum(groups[-1])   

people.sort(key = lambda x: x[-1], reverse = True)
```

which gives the desired result:

```
[
    [['E'], ['H', 'B', 'D'], 5346], 
    [['H'], ['E'], 4262], 
    [['B'], ['A', 'C', 'E', 'D'], 3947], 
    [['D'], ['B', 'E'], 2679], 
    [['I'], 2145], 
    [['G'], 1596], 
    [['F'], 1366], 
    [['C'], ['B'], 1321], 
    [['A'], ['B'], 1203]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of iterating the items in the dictionary and testing whether they are in the list, you should do it the other way around: Iterate the items in the lists and get their value from the dictionary (if any). This way, it's much faster, as lookup in a list is *O(n)*, whereas its more like *O(1)* in a dictionary. Also, there seems to be no need for all those intermediate lists of numbers; just add the sums and add those to the list at the end.

```
for groups in people:
    s = 0
    for i in range(min(len(groups), num_dos)):
        s += sum(dollars.get(x, 0) for x in groups[i])
    groups.append(s)
```

Comment: Update: Did some analysis using IPython's `%timeit` function, and my versions seems to be about twice as fast, but of course this heavily depends on, e.g. the number of elements in those lists and in the dict.